# Как сменить фон виджета GtkDrawingArea в gtk?

Tags: c, gui, gtk, виджет, gtk+

работаю над GTK приложением, возник вопрос как сменить фон виджета GtkDrawingArea. Встроенных функций для взаимодействия с этим виджетом нет. Я смотрел есть ли соответствующие функции для виджетов вообще, но функции `gtk_widget_set_style`, `gtk_widget_override_background_color`, устарели, как там написано, и я не могу их использовать.

Поэтому я дальше пополз в документацию, разыскал там функцию `gtk_render_background` начал про неё читать, как оказалось она все настройки цвета берёт из аргумента с типом `GtkStyleContext`, я начал искать как можно в нём сменить цвет фона, нашёл `gtk_style_context_set_background` которая, как оказалось устарела и не может быть боле использована, вместо неё предлагается использовать `gtk_render_background` порочный круг замкнулся, подумал я, возможно я ошибся и настройки фона закладываются в аргумент с типом `cairo_t`, но все мои попытки сменить цвет фона через возможности библиотеки cairo оказались тщетны.

Код:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean draw_callback(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window;  
    GtkWidget *main_box;
    GtkWidget *draw_area;

    cairo_t *cr;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // init window
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "gbl");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    // init main_box
    main_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 1);

    // init drawing area
    draw_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(draw_area, 800, 600);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(draw_area), "draw",
                    G_CALLBACK(draw_callback), NULL);

    // pack main_box
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_box), draw_area, TRUE, TRUE, 1);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), main_box);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}

gboolean draw_callback(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data) {
    guint width, height;
    GdkRGBA color;
    GtkStyleContext *context;

    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(widget);

    width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget);
    height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget);

    gtk_render_background(context, cr, 0, 0, width, height);

    cairo_arc(cr,
        width / 2.0, height / 2.0,
        MIN (width, height) / 2.0,
        0, 2 * G_PI);

    gtk_style_context_get_color(context,
            gtk_style_context_get_state(context),
            &color);
    gdk_cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, &color);

    cairo_fill(cr);

 return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: @Alex F, предложенный Вами вариант не подойдёт, ибо `gtk_widget_modify_fg` устаревшая функция, и не может быть мною использована.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответ довольно прост и банален, воспользуйтесь `cairo_paint` для окраски фона, добавив его после `gtk_render_background`, следующим образом:

```c
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0); // Выбираем цвет, в нашем случае красный
cairo_paint(cr); // Окрашиваем фон
```